# Cannot retrieve the id of the dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created HTML elements dynamically in JavaScript with ids.

When getting value separately it works. But I used jQuery to handle the click operation which updates the  database with id, and I am getting the id as undefined. The code is as follows.

Script:

```
var bt=document.createElement("b");
bt.setAttribute("class","assign");

var ah=document.createElement("a");
ah.href="";
ah.setAttribute('id',jsonobj[k]);
ah.id=jsonobj[k];
ah.innerHTML="Assign";

bt.appendChild(ah);
lb.appendChild(bt);
```

jQuery:

```
$('b.assign a').click(function(event) {
    var id1 = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id1);
});
```

Comment: If `jsonobj[k]` correct?

Comment: I think @epascarello must be right. If there was no ID, you'd get an empty string instead of undefined. So `jsonobj[k]` is likely `undefined`.

Comment: I filled in the blanks and code works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/JUczN/, you need to show more code so we can help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try delegating the click handler, so it will automatically work for any newly-created tags:

```
$(document).on('click','b.assign a',function(event) {
    var id1 = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id1);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: But it seems as though the click handler is bound, since OP is getting a response of undefined.